# How to set the hair_mesh to follow the animation?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

How to set the hair mesh to follow the animation?
I am trying this.

```
.cpp
Hair = CreateDefaultSubobject<USkeletalMeshComponent>("Hair");
    Hair->SetupAttachment(GetMesh());
    Hair->AttachToComponent(MyCharacter::GetMesh(), FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepWorldTransform, TEXT("head"));

.h
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    class USkeletalMeshComponent* Hair;
```

[image: RESULT]

I have attached the hair mesh to the `Head` socket but the hair mesh is not following the animation.
The hair mesh is called `Hair_Mesh` and has been attached in the editor while the `Hair` skeletal mesh component is already sets to `UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")`

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, the hair is attaching to the mesh but isn't animating.

You can set the Hair component to use the animation of the mesh by calling it's Master Pose Component.

```
Hair->SetMasterPoseComponent(GetMesh());
```

You put this in your cpp constructor under where you've attached it to the mesh.

Comment: Not working for me (

Comment: What happens if you remove or comment out the line beginning Hair->AttachToComponent ?

Comment: After commenting this line the Hairs mesh is not following the head and animations in the lobby, and when un-commenting the line, the hairs mesh is following the head only in the lobby but in the editor not following.

Answer (score -1):

```
**.h**
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, NonTransactional, meta = (Category = "Default", OverrideNativeName = "Hair"))
        USkeletalMeshComponent* Hair;
    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, BlueprintReadWrite, meta = (DisplayName = "Skin Met R", Category = "SkeletalMesh", MultiLine = "true", OverrideNativeName = "SkinMetR"))
        UMaterialInstanceDynamic* SkinMetR;
    AMyCharacter(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer = FObjectInitializer::Get());
    virtual void PostLoadSubobjects(FObjectInstancingGraph* OuterInstanceGraph) override;
    static void CustomDynamicClassInitialization(UDynamicClass* InDynamicClass);
    static void StaticDependenciesAssets(TArray<FBlueprintDependencyData>& AssetsToLoad);
    static void StaticDependencies_DirectlyUsedAssets(TArray<FBlueprintDependencyData>& AssetsToLoad);
virtual void UserConstructionScript();
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, meta = (Category = "SkeletalMesh", OverrideNativeName = "InitSkeletalMesh"))
        virtual void InitSkeletalMesh()


**.cpp**
void AMyCharacter::InitSkeletalMesh(){
bool CallFunc_K2_AttachToComponent_ReturnValue{};
    if(::IsValid(Hair))
    {
        CallFunc_K2_AttachToComponent_ReturnValue = Hair->USceneComponent::K2_AttachToComponent((*(AccessPrivateProperty<USkeletalMeshComponent* >((this), ACharacter::Mesh() ))), FName(TEXT("head")), EAttachmentRule::KeepWorld, EAttachmentRule::KeepWorld, EAttachmentRule::KeepWorld, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me (

Comment: Welcome to GDSE & thankyou for contributing. This answer could be improved by include an explanation of how it solves the problem & why you included these particular steps.